# Canon 750D vs 200D in low light and moving subjects?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation

I am about to make a DSLR purchase and have to choose between Canon EOS 750D and the recently introduced EOS 200D, which is available at almost the same price to me. After looking at all the specs all I decided to make a decision based on the low light performance and tracking of moving subjects.

The EOS 200D, with the dual pixel CMOS sensor boasts better subject tracking during videos. But I am only concerned about photos, where the 19 cross-type autofocus points of 750D sound better to me. Also, in low light conditions the EOS 200D features more ISO sensitivity, but having only 1 cross type autofocus point means that it would struggle more to focus the subject in low light, compared to 750D.

Can anyone tell me the practical differences between these two cameras under these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two cameras use a similar sensor, albeit the 200D natively supports ISO 25600, so it's slightly more sensitive in low-light situations. The 200D also uses the newer DIGIC 7 processor, so it's more responsive overall. As for subject tracking:

- If you're going to be shooting in Live View mode, the 200D wins hands down for having Dual Pixel focusing
- If you're shooting through the Viewfinder the 750D wins because it has more focusing points

Personally I'd avoid the dilemma by paying a bit more for the Canon 800D. As of 2017 the difference in pricing is merely $150.

Comment: Thanks @jonathan. 800D was more pricy on my side (Germany) but I ended up buying the 200D since I was getting a good discount on that. Now in retrospect I think 200D was a good deal considering the price to the overall features over 700D.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not an expert and don't use Cannon. I'm giving you a general idea.

1. Decide what you want to capture, pic or vdo. You can't have both in a single camera.
2. If you are not into high speed photography then tracking is not an issue as all DSLR are good at capturing high speed objects. All you need to do is, work on shutter speed, focusing, aperture, camera positioning etc.

The 19 cross-type autofocus points is a good one. The more the better.

3. For low light you have 2 options, `ISO` and `shutter speed`.

High ISO is not a good choice. The lower the ISO you use better it is (I try not to cross 600), some special cases are different.

Shutter speed controlled is the better option.

However, if you want to use the `Auto` Mode more then higher `ISO` is needed.

For low light lens is another factor. If you don't have a good low light lens then even with the correct setting you may not have a good pic. Just like `Macro` photography.

Comment: The OP has specific questions about the differences and tradeoffs between two specific cameras, that you are not addressing in your answer.

Comment: @scottbb I have said the basics. `Can anyone tell me the practical differences between these two cameras under these conditions?` This reply will always be a biased one and full of debates. Based on experience one can take quality pic with even a defective camera. Why should I decide a camera for him? He should judge which to buy.

Comment: Okay, but you say, _1. Decide what you want to capture, pic or vdo. You can't have both in a single camera._ Firstly, that's not entirely true, many DLSRs today are good at both photography and video. Secondly, OP said, _I am only concerned about photos_. So how is your point #1 helpful at all? And then you say, essentially, low ISO is better, but maybe not for special cases. That's so broadly vague, it doesn't seem very helpful. That's essentially "follow the rules of thumb, except for when you should break the rules." Why the rules? When should they be broken?

Comment: @scottbb 1) I feel suggesting somethig extra neither detoriate the quality of reply nor harmful. 2) There is exception and limitation to everything. Once you cross these limitations you cannot perform within the rules. That time you have to break it. I have already mentioned a situation when you need higher ISO. As a photographer's point of view that's a so so mode.